# Metaplex Auction House Buy Refund

Tags: metaplex

I run into a problem during Auction House Buy Process... since Phantom wallet expires the blockhash of transactions when users take more time to proceed with it. I wanted to find a way to return the funds at the time a bid was made but the execute process failed or wasn't completed before the blockhash expired. I would like to know if there's a way to solve this with or without using the CLI (due that on my side i will not have constant access to the auction house keypair).

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on the use case here? Do you mean you would like to return funds to unsuccessful bidders when a sale is executed? 

As for the expiration of the blockhash, that’s not a problem that’s unique to auctionhouse. If blockhash expires, you would typically regerate the transaction and then have the client to sign it again. You can do that as long as you keep the original instructions. Just remember to check that the blockhash has expired to avoid accidentally sending the transaction multiple times. 

If you clarify the question, Happy to provide a proper answer.

Comment: Can you please add some screenshot to support this its hard to give a proper answer without knowing what exactly is the error

Comment: Although you can use `Withdraw` instruction to withdraw back the funds from the Buyer Escrow Account to the buyer's wallet, I wouldn't recommend that as the bid will still be active but the escrow account will not have the required funds. What's the use case? can you elaborate more?